# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $S_7$ consisting of permutations that send $1,2,3$ to $1,2,3$ in some order. Is $H$ isomorphic to $S_3 \times S_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $S_7$ consisting of permutations that send $1,2,3$ to $1,2,3$ in some order. (The remaining values $4,5,6,7$ are still permuted just not to the positions $1,2$ or $3$.) Is $H$ isomorphic to $S_3 \times S_4$?

This turns out to be true, but I'm not sure how to get to the answer here. Shouldn't $H$ and $S_3 \times S_4$ share a bijective mapping since we're talking about permutations here? Clearly the cardinality of $S_3 \times S_4$ is greater than the cardinality of $H$ so there isn't a bijective map between them. What might be I missing here?

Comment: You are not correctly calculating the cardinality of $H$. To get you thinking about it right, note that both $(123)$ *and* $(123)(45)(67)$ are elements of $H$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ah I see the cardinality of $S_7$ would be $7!$, but this doesn't tell me about the cardinality of $H$...

Comment: As witten, i.e., "Let $H$ be **a** subgroup of $S_7$ consisting of [some?] permutations ...", all we know is that $H$ is a (possibly proper) *subgroup* of the obvious embedding of $S_3\times S_4$ in $S_7$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I assume that $H$ is *the* subgroup of *all the* permutations of $S_7$ that send ecc.)

In general, given a set $X$ and a subset $Y\subseteq X$, the set:

$$H:=\{f\in S_X\mid f(Y)=Y\}=\{f\in S_X\mid f_{|Y}\in S_Y\}$$

is indeed a subgroup of $S_X$. In fact:

- (closure) $f,g\in H\Rightarrow (fg)(Y)=f(g(Y))\stackrel{(g\in H)}{=}f(Y)\stackrel{(f\in H)}{=}Y\Rightarrow fg\in H$;
- (inverse) $f\in H\Rightarrow Y=(f^{-1}f)(Y)=f^{-1}(f(Y))\stackrel{(f\in H)}{=}f^{-1}(Y)\Rightarrow f^{-1}\in H$.

Let's define $K:=\{f\in S_X\mid f(X\setminus Y)=X\setminus Y\}=\{f\in S_X\mid f_{|X\setminus Y}\in S_{X\setminus Y}\}$. Note that $K=H$.

Consider the map $\varphi\colon H\to S_Y\times S_{X\setminus Y}$ defined by $f\mapsto(f_{|Y},f_{|X\setminus Y})$. This is well defined, because $f\in H\Rightarrow f_{|Y}$ is onto $Y$ (and hence $f_{|Y}\in S_Y$), and $f\in H\Rightarrow f\in K\Rightarrow f_{|X\setminus Y}$ is onto $X\setminus Y$ (and hence $f_{|X\setminus Y}\in S_{X\setminus Y}$). Let's check for the injectivity of $\varphi$:

\begin{alignat}{1}
\varphi(f)=\varphi(g) &\Longrightarrow (f_{|Y}=g_{|Y})\wedge(f_{|X\setminus Y}=g_{|X\setminus Y}) \Longrightarrow f=g
\end{alignat}

Surjectivity of $\varphi$: $\forall (h,k)\in S_Y\times S_{X\setminus Y}$, define $f\in\operatorname{Maps}(X)$ by $f_{|Y}:=h$ and $f_{|X\setminus Y}:=k$; then $f\in H$ and $\varphi(f)=(h,k)$.

Finally, since $g\in H, y\in Y\Rightarrow g(y)=g_{|Y}(y)\in Y$, we get $\forall f,g\in H, \forall y\in Y$:

\begin{alignat}{1}
(fg)_{|Y}(y) &= (fg)(y) \\
&= f(g(y)) \\
&= f(g_{|Y}(y)) \\
&= f_{|Y}(g_{|Y}(y))= \\
&= (f_{|Y}g_{|Y})(y) \\
\end{alignat}

whence $(fg)_{|Y}=f_{|Y}g_{|Y}$. Likewise, $(fg)_{|X\setminus Y}=f_{|X\setminus Y}g_{|X\setminus Y}$. So, finally:

\begin{alignat}{1}
\varphi(fg) &= ((fg)_{|Y},(fg)_{|X\setminus Y}) \\
&= (f_{|Y}g_{|Y},f_{|X\setminus Y}g_{|X\setminus Y}) \\
&= (f_{|Y},f_{|X\setminus Y})(g_{|Y},g_{|X\setminus Y}) \\
&= \varphi(f)\varphi(g) \\ 
\end{alignat}

Therefore, $H(=K)\cong S_Y\times S_{X\setminus Y}$, and yours is just the particular case for $X:=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and $Y:=\{1,2,3\}$.

Answer (score 1):

*1 In combinatorics*

In how many ways can you make a seven-digit number from *1,2,...,6,7* without repetition (Group $S_7$) with *1,2,3* on the first three positions and *4,5,6,7* on the remaining four position? (description of $H$).

Well, you have six ways how to order the first three digits ($S_3$) and $4!=24$ ways how to arrange remaining digits ($S_4$).

*In group theory*

You define $\Phi: H\to S_3\times S_4$ by sending $\pi\in H$ on pair $(\pi_3, \pi_4)$ where by $\pi_3$ I mean permutation $\pi$ restricted on the subet $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\pi_4$ means permutation $\pi$ restricted on the subset $\{4,5,6,7\}$.

You can check that this is isomorphism.